# Add custom button to Sharepoint 2013 ribbon to print

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I need to create a shortcut for my client to print a document from a SharePoint library.  The user needs to select a file in the library and then in the ribbon click on the custom Print button.  This should active the windows print dialog where you can select the printer and copies. It should print the content of the document.
Please help how I can add a custom button and what actions should be added to the button?  I am not familiar with Visual Studio or JavaScript but from research I see one can use JavaScript.  But I need to know what JavaScript to enter?